# CSS/HTML Slider... <li> reverse direction needed

Tags: html, css, slider, html-lists, z-index

This is CSS/html based Slider is but i want in reverse direction.. first **< li >** image should come up and so on... in fact i want direct of slides should be from LEFT to RIGHT.. not right to left...

http://jsfiddle.net/Qrw76

```
HTML Code here

<div class="accordian">
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="image_title"></div>
    <a href="adv"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x348"/></a>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="image_title"></div>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x348"/></a>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="image_title"></div>
    <a href="adv"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x348"/></a>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="image_title"></div>
    <a href="adv"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x348"/></a>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="image_title"></div>
    <a href="adv"><img src="http://placehold.it/640x348"/></a>
</li>

</ul>
</div>


CSS here
===========
* {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
}

.accordian {
width: 820px; height: 348px;
overflow: hidden;

/*Time for some styling*/
margin: 100px auto;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

/*A small hack to prevent flickering on some browsers*/
.accordian ul {
width: 2000px;
/*This will give ample space to the last item to move
instead of falling down/flickering during hovers.*/
}

.accordian li {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 120px;
float: left;
border-left: 1px solid #888;

box-shadow: 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 25px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

/*Transitions to give animation effect*/
transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
/*If you hover on the images now you should be able to 
see the basic accordian*/
}

/*Reduce with of un-hovered elements*/
.accordian ul:hover li {width: 40px;

}
/*Lets apply hover effects now*/
/*The LI hover style should override the UL hover style*/
.accordian ul li:hover {width: 600px;
}

.accordian li img {
display: block;
}

/*Image title styles*/
.image_title {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
position: absolute;
left: 0; bottom: 0; 
width: 640px;   
}
.image_title a {
display: block;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 20px;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Your images go left to right and right to left, do not understand your problem.

Comment: No javascript / JQuery given in example code. **You at least have to demonstrate what you have tried so far.**

Comment: see the pic.. please @Izekid
http://s10.postimg.org/fcdbyqg21/direction.jpg

Comment: @Paulie_D no jquery/js used.. only html/css see the http://jsfiddle.net/Qrw76

Comment: what i want is slider should open in opposite direction...

Comment: your question is not getting...

Comment: here I re-phrase my question in simple words... [link](http://bit.ly/1rtfKIM)